# Symfony2: Full path to action/route in a controller

Tags: symfony, controller

I need the full path to a action inside my controller, to send it via email. How can I achieve something like `{{ path('_route') }}` from inside my controller but the full path?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Juan's answer is right if you want the local path. The absolute path — which is helpful to be send through email — needs extra parameter(s):

```php
$url = $this->generateUrl('your_route_name', array(), true);
```

The third parameter indicates that the absolute path is to be generated.

If you want to use this URL in your view just add the `$url` to the response array in your action and use it.

Comment: Actually, to generate an absolute URL in Twig, use the `url()` function instead of `path()`.

Comment: I used with TRUE, it was only working in my local but not on remote server so I changed the third param to UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL as given in this asnwer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38823820/4380588 and now it is working on both local as well as remote servers

Answer (score 32):

**Symfony 3+**

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

$this->generateUrl('your_route_name', array('/* your route parameters */'), UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the up to date solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$url = $this->generateUrl('your_route_name');
```